# html "data-" attribute as javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

Lets say I have this:

```
<div data-uid="aaa" data-name="bbb", data-value="ccc" onclick="fun(this.data.uid, this.data-name, this.data-value)">
```

And this:

```
function fun(one, two, three) {
    //some code
}
```

Well this is not working but I have absolutely no idea why. could someone post a working example please?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The easiest way to get `data-*` attributes is with `element.getAttribute()`:

```
onclick="fun(this.getAttribute('data-uid'), this.getAttribute('data-name'), this.getAttribute('data-value'));"
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pm6cH/

---

Although I would suggest just passing `this` to `fun()`, and getting the 3 attributes **inside** the `fun` function:

```
onclick="fun(this);"
```

And then:

```
function fun(obj) {
    var one = obj.getAttribute('data-uid'),
        two = obj.getAttribute('data-name'),
        three = obj.getAttribute('data-value');
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pm6cH/1/

---

The new way to access them by property is with `dataset`, but that isn't supported by all browsers. You'd get them like the following:

```
this.dataset.uid
// and
this.dataset.name
// and
this.dataset.value
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pm6cH/2/

---

**Also note that in your HTML, there shouldn't be a comma here:**

```
data-name="bbb",
```

---

**References:**

- `element.getAttribute()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getAttribute
- `.dataset`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset
- `.dataset` browser compatibility: http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: @lan Passing "this" is way better. Thank you.

Comment: @user2206656 Agreed :) I added (very simple) demos for each of the scenarios, so hopefully that helps too!

Comment: Hey, this may be a little late, but is there some way to trigger the function without 'onclick' but rather something like 'onload'?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery you can easily fetch the data attributes by

```
$(this).data("id") or $(event.target).data("id")
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that the syntax is `this.dataset.whatever`.

Your code should look like this:

```
<div data-uid="aaa" data-name="bbb" data-value="ccc"
    onclick="fun(this.dataset.uid, this.dataset.name, this.dataset.value)">
```

**Another important note:** Javascript will always strip out hyphens and make the data attributes camelCase, regardless of whatever capitalization you use. `data-camelCase` will become `this.dataset.camelcase` and `data-Camel-case` will become `this.dataset.camelCase`.

jQuery (after v1.5 and later) *always* uses lowercase, regardless of your capitalization.

So when referencing your data attributes using this method, remember the camelCase:

```
<div data-this-is-wild="yes, it's true"
    onclick="fun(this.dataset.thisIsWild)">
```

Also, you don't need to use commas to separate attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div data-uid="aaa" data-name="bbb", data-value="ccc" onclick="fun(this)">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function fun(obj) {
    var uid= $(obj).attr('data-uid');
    var name= $(obj).attr('data-name');
    var value= $(obj).attr('data-value');
}
```

but I'm using jQuery.

Comment: + there is the `.data()` method in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
function fun(obj) {
    var uid= $(obj).data('uid');
    var name= $(obj).data('name');
    var value= $(obj).data('value');
}
```

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you might use default parameters in your function
and then just pass the entire dataset itself, since the
dataset is already a DOMStringMap Object

```
<div data-uid="aaa" data-name="bbb" data-value="ccc"
onclick="fun(this.dataset)">

<script>
const fun = ({uid:'ddd', name:'eee', value:'fff', other:'default'} = {}) { 
    // 
}
</script>
```

that way, you can deal with any data-values that got set in the html tag,
or use defaults if they weren't set - that kind of thing

maybe not in this situation, but in others, it might be advantageous to put all
your preferences in a single data-attribute

```
<div data-all='{"uid":"aaa","name":"bbb","value":"ccc"}'
onclick="fun(JSON.parse(this.dataset.all))">
```

there are probably more terse ways of doing that, if you already know
certain things about the order of the data

```
<div data-all="aaa,bbb,ccc" onclick="fun(this.dataset.all.split(','))">
```