# Get Attributes Value for multiple class

Tags: javascript, html, class

Im a Javascript beginner. I want to get attribute value on multiple class elements. I tried with IDs, but it's not revelent since IDs are supposed to be unique.

My HTML looks like this :

```
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="myJavascriptFunc()" data="FooBar_1">
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="myJavascriptFunc()" data="FooBar_2">
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="myJavascriptFunc()" data="FooBar_3">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Do you want to get data attribute here?

Comment: Ty Choco, but how can i get the value the attribute "data" corresponding the <a> element the user clicked on? (I hope it makes sence, my english is not really good)

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16566321/1374307).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First close your anchor Tags

```
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="return myJavascriptFunc(this);" data="FooBar_1">Test1</a>
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="return myJavascriptFunc(this)" data="FooBar_2">Test2</a>
<a href="#" class="Test" onclick="return myJavascriptFunc(this)" data="FooBar_3">Test3</a>
```

then use this javascript function

```
function myJavascriptFunc(item)
{
    alert(item.getAttribute("data"));
    return false

}
```

and let me know if it works

Comment: ok please accept the answer it may help help to some one who is searching

Answer (score 1):

Trying using this:

```
function test(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var val = x[i].innerHTML;    //innerHTML returns the written text inside the element tag
        alert(val);     
        alert(x[i].getAttribute("data"));  //this will give you the data attribute
    }
}
```

You can get any other attribute you like from that element just by replacing the innerHTML by that attribute's name

Comment: What's the difference with Choco answer? I mean is it better to you use your function?

Comment: Its just a different method to achieve to the same objective. Instead of accessing by element, I have accessed them by classname. You don't have to bind each object with the on-click event in this method. So in case you want similar functionality somewhere else on the page, you can directly give them 'test' class. But for the current scenario, I think Choco's answer is more apt

Answer (score 0):

I'm too late as always, but I would use the HTML 5 dataset attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  function doSomething(classname,func,datakey)
  {
    var hrefs = document.getElementsByClassName(classname), // get all elements with the class
    i = 0; // initialize the loop
    for(;i < hrefs.length; i++) // iterate through all elements
    {
      func(hrefs[i].dataset[datakey]); // execute the passed function with the content of the dataset as first argument
    }
  }
  function alertval(value) // example function to do something with it
  {
    alert(value);
  }
  window.onload = function ()
  {
    doSomething("Test",alertval,"something"); // just test it
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="Test" data-something="FooBar_1">Test1</a>
  <a href="#" class="Test" data-something="FooBar_2">Test2</a>
  <a href="#" class="Test" data-something="FooBar_3">Test3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wondering why you can't just reach the `data` attribute using the `this` keyword from `myJavascriptFunc()`. That's because you are using inline event registration, and the `this` keyword then refers to the `window` object. To get around this you must make sure the `this` keyword is actually written into the `onclick` property.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = myJavascriptFunc;
}

function myJavascriptFunc() {
  alert(this.getAttribute('data'));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="test" data="FooBar_1">FooBar_One</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="test" data="FooBar_2">FooBar_Two</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="test" data="FooBar_3">FooBar_Three</a>
</body>

</html>
```

A way to see the difference:

`<element onclick="myJavascriptFunc()">`. // `this` refers to the `window` object as the element does not get passed along.

`<element onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('data'));">`. // `this` refers to the element.