# how to get html data attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

How do I get the data attributes "name" and "description" in javascript?
(user clicks on button, display value)

```
<form action="http://serverhost/postdata" method="POST">
  <script src="myscript.js" class="blue-button" 
  data-name="aaa" 
  data-description="bbb"
  </script>
< /form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get list of data-\* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Not jQuery. No dup.

Comment: @RandyCasburn It's got both. But you like this one better? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566299/html-data-attribute-as-javascript-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get data attributes in JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/get-data-attributes-in-javascript-code)

Comment: They are all sooooo indirect. This is a simple, direct question. Requires a simple, direct answer. But the folks with giant rep like you can decide. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
document.querySelector('script.blue-button').dataset
```

Here is the reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 1):

First you should close the opening script tag (makes the syntax high lighting work and is easier to read)

```
<form action="http://serverhost/postdata" method="POST">
  <script src="myscript.js" class="blue-button" 
  data-name="aaa" 
  data-description="bbb">
  </script>
</form>
```

Then all you would have to do is

```
document.querySelector('script.blue-button').dataset
```