# JavaScript get element value in Input by jsname

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to scrape data from an html file. Specifically, I need the value of a variable in an input. Below I have an example of an input and what I have tried to do so far (I am specifically trying to get the "data-inital-value:

Input:

```
<input type="username" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your username" name="usernamefield" autocapitalize="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="trying to get this" badinput="false">
```

My code:

```
<script>
    String uname = document.getElementById('usernamefield').value
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html "data-" attribute as javascript parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566299/html-data-attribute-as-javascript-parameter)

Comment: There's no `id="usernamefield"` attribute in your HTML, what is `getElementById()` supposed to find?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getAttribute`

**Note:** `document.getElementById('usernamefield')` to select the input element but there is `id` attribute on that input element. Either add the `id` or select using any other way.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
console.log(input.getAttribute('data-initial-value'))
```

```html
<input type="username" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your username" name="usernamefield" autocapitalize="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="trying to get this" badinput="false">
```

As the attribute you need is prefixed with `data` you can get it using `dataset`. Note that when you will use `dataset` the property name will be converted to camelCase. For example `initial-value` will be converted to `initalValue`

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
console.log(input.dataset.initialValue)
```

```html
<input type="username" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your username" name="usernamefield" autocapitalize="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="trying to get this" badinput="false">
```

Comment: OP's problem starts earlier. Their element has no `id="usernamefield"` so `getElementById('usernamefield')` cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but for everyone who needs it.

Use can use the `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` for it.

```js
document.querySelector("div[jsname='something']")
```

You can also write in the `[]` every attribute you want like `data-attributes`.

Hope I can help something :D